# Punch Line Marketing

Tags: seo, optimization, marketing, google-website-optimizer, google-adsense

There are so many "punch line" websites like:

http://www.thatswhyyoufail.com

www.canrailsscale.com/

www.nooooooooooooooo.com/

but it's a mystery how they ever get so popular.

I have an idea for a punch line website too, but I want to make it BIG!
Does anyone have any tips for marketing these kinds of sites?

p.s. and no, I do not own any of these sites, and am not disguising it as a question to market them lol.

Answer (score 1):

> it's a mystery how they ever get so
>   popular

For humor,* word of mouth online (digg.com, reddit.com, stumbleupon.com, community forums, and e-mail) and offline ("did you hear about ...") is all it takes to get people talking about the "punch line" (a.k.a. the "[meme](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&q=define%3Ameme&aq=f&aqi=g4g-o1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1)") and drive traffic.

Note: The same cannot be said for most other categories of web site offerings.

Comment: Well, that's actually true of all types of website, and it's the principle that search engines like Google operate on. It's just hard to get people excited enough about your CRM software/B2B service/aluminum solenoid valves/etc. to actually link to your page and promote your products by word of mouth.

Comment: Turning things back around to the original question: if it's funny/salacious/interesting enough, it just needs to be released and it will spread on its own... (conversely, no amount of spamming social media networks will make a dull product or service worth talking about)

Comment: I agree.  I don't get why people keeping spamming various websites with their own boring websites.

Answer (score 1):

Sites like acid cow, bored.com etc are worth aproaching to see if they will take up your punchline. short of that its really down to if your site is funny/engaging enough.

One thing that might work is getting your punchine to be spread by some influential social media users and forum mods etc...